# Run the bat file outside the jar file folder

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have a jar file and a bat file inside the same folder. I created the jar file from the Eclipse by using export

In the bat file, I have the code like this below

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar main.jar -o true
PAUSE
```

I can run the jar file no problem because it is in the same folder. However, if I place my bat file let say on my desktop, I cannot run the jar file. I am wondering is there a way to run my bat file without running it inside the same folder of the jar file?

Comment: What's *happening* when it doesn't run? I mean, you have to reference the actual location of the jar file; are you?

Comment: In the cmd, it said Error, Unable to access jarfile main.jar

Comment: but how do I reference a location of my jar file? Let say my jar file is at this location ` C:\Users\admin\workspace\Main `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the main.jar with the absolute or relative (i.e. from the location of the bat file) path of the jar file.

**using absolute path:**

bat file like this:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar C:\Users\admin\workspace\Main\main.jar -o true
PAUSE
```

**using relative path:**

bat file in C:\Users\admin\Desktop like this:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar ..\workspace\Main\main.jar -o true
PAUSE
```

Comment: Hi Peter thank you for your respond, can you give a example? thanks

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try

Comment: In fact you should not need the quotes on the filename, http://superuser.com/a/586959/259164 explains when you would need quotes (paths with spaces)

Comment: Its there a way to refer all the files in my folder? Let say I have things like log4j.properties inside as well in the same folder

Comment: @Amazed Then you're in a bit of trouble, since you cannot specify a classpath when you specify the `-jar` option. You'd need to provide something like a system property/etc to indicate config file locations, then load them manually if they're not in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

In the batch file you can change to the directory before executing the command.

```
cd ..\workspace\Main
java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar main.jar -o true
PAUSE
```

If you want the current working directory to remain in the location of the batch file add setlocal before changing directory

```
setlocal
cd ..\workspace\Main
java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar main.jar -o true
PAUSE
```